# How to change the status of the trigger if the previous execution takes longer than the actual time

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

If a task is scheduled to run for every 5 min and the task is running longer than that in that case I want to delete the next trigger from the queue or any other alternative solution would be also fine.

Example:
the task is scheduled at `12:00`, so the next trigger would be at `12:05` and `12:10` and so on.
if trigger at `12:00` finishes its execution at `12:07` in that case I want the task to wait for the next trigger that is `12:10` not to continue immediately which is what happens currently.

Answer (score 0):

These are the options:

`schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *'` - will give you 12:00, 12:05, 12:10 - a new run will start on schedule as soon as it arrives.

`schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)` - will give you a run 5 minutes after the last run was ended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. here the problem is not about the trigger interval. I'm using this in my task```schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)``` but the problem is the task continues to run immediately if the last execution takes more than 5 minutes to finish.

Comment: @Markel Use max_active_dag_runs=1

Comment: It is already set, there is only one instance of the task running at the time.

Comment: Sorry but what you are writing doesn't make sense for the timedelta. If this is what you are experiencing than this is a bug. Please open a github issue with repreduce example https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues